# RS-485: what happens when bus contention occurs

Tags: communication, digital-communications, rs485, common-mode

I'm refering to an half-duplex RS485 application which consists of a master and multiple slaves like in the circuit below (I'm using an [ST3485](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/389/st3485eb-1850066.pdf)).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faoIbW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From my understanding, the drivers outputs are tri-stated (high impedance when receiving, high/low when transmitting). As RS-485 transmition is done using a common mode signal, I believe that the devices do not neccessarily have to share common ground (is that true?), but in my case, the master provides the slaves with power, so I'm going to have a ground connection.

My question is, what will happen in case of a bus contention, so if e.g. both slaves transmit data at the same time? Sure, the data received by the master will be corrupted, but does this also harm the drivers?

If yes, what measures are typically taken to protect the drivers?

Comment: RS485 is not a current loop - it *does* require a ground/common wire in addition to the signal pair.

Comment: "is done using a common mode signal" -- you mean differential mode signal.  Common mode is when both wires move the same direction.  You should edit your question for clarity.

Comment: But contention is typically survivable at a *hardware* level.  Rather the focus is on software/protocol schemes to avoid it; eg, the simple case where one device "owns" the bus and the others only answer in direct response to queries from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RS-485 does need to share a reference for communication. The allowed maximum difference between grounds of different nodes is +/- 7V, so without providing a common ground reference between nodes, the voltage might be exceeded and nodes could get damaged or at least they would not communicate properly. The common ground reference might be a separate wire between devices, or for example devices could be referenced via mains earth.

When two devices drive a bus to opposing state, a lot of current flows and the voltage level is indeterminate. Fortunately, the datasheet of the driver you have says the outputs have overload protection.

Standard protection procedures include series resistances or self-resetting polyfuses, but in general, the drivers are able to protect themselves from occasional bus contention.

Answer (score 1):

> *As RS-485 transmition is done using a common mode signal*

It's a differential signal and thus avoids common mode noise problems to a greater extent. It's also not a fully floating signal and so it helps a lot to have a common ground (usually a cable screen) to tie sub-systems together such as here: -

[image]

[Picture source](http://www.ozeki.hu/p_5851-ozeki-rs485.html). Note that a galvanic isolation might only be required in certain circumstances when one device (the PC in this case) might have an ambiguous earth connection.

> *My question is, what will happen in case of a bus contention, so if
> e.g. both slaves transmit data at the same time? Sure, the data
> received by the master will be corrupted, but does this also harm the
> drivers?*

No, it won't harm the drivers but neither should it happen very often because you "guarantee" you have a non-flaky system by ensuring that what is transmitted to the slaves is appended with a checksum. The slaves will only respond if the data packet looks good. Minimal chance of an error.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, what will happen in case of a bus contention, so if e.g. both slaves transmit data at the same time? Sure, the data received by the master will be corrupted, but does this also harm the drivers?

RS485 is a *standard*; RS485 drivers are *products*.

All the RS485 drivers that I know about will stand up to that sort of treatment, but that doesn't mean they all will.  It's up to you to scrutinize the data sheet.  (Any claim that they can stand short circuits probably mean that they'll deal with your situation).